# Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead With Static Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I need to use typeahead for very large data. Generation of data consumes 4-5 seconds. So I cannot make Ajax calls each time. I download and cache the data upon user request. My code is the following:

```
$("#build-package-list-btn").click(function(){
        $.get**JSON**("/packages", function(data){
            // data is an array
            $("#typeahead-packages").typeahead({source:data});
            console.log(data == null); // returns false
        });
    })
```

It gives no error but whenever I try to write to typeahead text box, it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of null bootstrap.js:1644
Typeahead.matcher bootstrap.js:1644
(anonymous function) bootstrap.js:1631
e.extend.grep jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
Typeahead.lookup bootstrap.js:1630
Typeahead.keyup bootstrap.js:1738
e.extend.proxy.g jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
```

My typeahead is like this (JADE)

```
input#typeahead-packages(type="text",data-provide="typeahead")
```

Also in the Chrome Console I tried:

```
 $("#typeahead-packages").typeahead({source:["abcdef","abcddd","abcccc"]});
```

But typeahead does not give an error but it also does not work. I cannot find what am I doing wrong. I am using the 2.0.4 bootstrap.

**EDIT:** I changed it to getJSON from get it did not help. However when I construct data like this, it is working:

```
data = [new String((data[0])), new String((data[5]))];
```

Comment: You didn't check `data`, so it may very well be a string or an object or anything. More over, your debug test may not be not working because you can only initialize the plugin once. Can you provide the actual data ?

Comment: data is just an array of strings I have also tried giving some arbittary data controlled

Comment: oh I see the error now @Sherbrow you cannot make it twice, weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update, the problem comes from the JSON.

> ### jQuery.getJSON()
>
> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.
> ([source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/))

You should concentrate on the source of the items. be sure that this is an array of strings. Your error suggest `data` is a string.

You can use the Chrome Console (or any of your choice), under the *Network tab*, and spy on the actual results of your AJAX request. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is an interesting tool to validate your result.

Then your next problem will be to update the source of an already initialized typeahead. You can use the following code :

```js
var $myTypeahead = $('#myTypeahead');
var typeaheadObj = $myTypeahead.data('typeahead');
if(typeaheadObj) typeaheadObj.source = ["abc", "cde"];
```

[Example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/bTzZm/)